# Postgres sql prompt

Tags: sql-interactive-mode

I have connected to my remote postgres db via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65310225/5065796

I am able to query and interact just fine.  I cannot, however, see the prompt.  It's just a blank line.  It looks like this:

```
\c
You are now connected to database "yourdb" as user "youruser".
| <-- my cursor is here
```

I've read all over and the usual response is that there's a problem with the sql prompt regexp.  No combination of any of the following, including restarting the connection, and even restarting Emacs, produces any prompt.

```lisp
; spaces on the end
(sql-set-product-feature 'postgres :prompt-regexp "^[-[:alnum:]_]*=[#>] ")
(sql-set-product-feature 'postgres :prompt-cont-regexp "^[-[:alnum:]_]*=[#>] ")

(sql-set-product-feature 'postgres :prompt-regexp "^\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\|-\\)*=[#>] ")
(sql-set-product-feature 'postgres :prompt-cont-regexp "^\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\|-\\)*[-(][#>] ")

; no spaces on the end
(sql-set-product-feature 'postgres :prompt-regexp "^[-[:alnum:]_]*=[#>]")
(sql-set-product-feature 'postgres :prompt-cont-regexp "^[-[:alnum:]_]*=[#>]")

(sql-set-product-feature 'postgres :prompt-regexp "^\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\|-\\)*=[#>]")
(sql-set-product-feature 'postgres :prompt-cont-regexp "^\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\|-\\)*[-(][#>]")
```

Each change is reflected in the `sql-product-alist`.  For instance, the last calls to `sql-set-product-feature` appear as:

```lisp
(postgres :name "Postgres" :free-software t :font-lock sql-mode-postgres-font-lock-keywords :sqli-program sql-postgres-program :sqli-options sql-postgres-options :sqli-login sql-postgres-login-params :sqli-comint-func sql-comint-postgres :list-all
           ("\\d+" . "\\dS+")
           :list-table
           ("\\d+ %s" . "\\dS+ %s")
           :completion-object sql-postgres-completion-object :prompt-regexp "^\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\|-\\)*=[#>]" :prompt-length 12 :prompt-cont-regexp "^\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\|-\\)*[-(][#>]" :input-filter sql-remove-tabs-filter :terminator
           ("\\(^\\s-*\\\\g\\|;\\)" . "\\g"))
```

I have loaded psql in a non-Emacs prompt and connected.  Taking the various prompts, things like,

```
AB_CDE_FG=>
aoeu=>
```

I have run `regexp-builder` using the above expressions and they match.

So, if it's not the prompt regexp, what could it be?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, unfortunately.